# How can I change the partition name on a qcow2 image in a way that can be automated?

Tags: partition, disk-image

I have resized a Debian qcow2 image with `qemu-img` and `virt-resize`. This breaks the image because it renames the partitions from sda1, sda14 and sda15 to sda1, sda2 and sda3. I am searching for a tool that allows me to change those names back whilst also allowing me to maintain the flow automatic. I am using `Ansible` for my automation.

I have looked and it doesn't seem like `virt-resize` has the ability to preserve partition names, which to mean seems like really bad design. But it might just be me being a noob. I have come across `virt-rescue` which seems like it can do the job but it's interactive so I can't automate it.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

From the context of the question I assume GPT. This can be done via sfdisk:

```
sfdisk --dump /dev/sdx > partitions.sfdisk # dump partition table into human readable format
sed -i 's|sdx2|sdx14|g' partitions.sfdisk # make your changes
sfdisk /dev/sdx < partitions.sfdisk # write changed partition table to device
```

However, I must tell you: The necessity of this change is the administrator's version of a code-smell. Device names sure were important in the past. Today, all relevant parts of the system (bootloader, mounter,…) should be using UUIDs or labels.

Comment: Thank you for your reply ! I am still googling and struggling. I think a pertinent point to make is that the disk has no label. When I use `parted` and then `print` it says error unrecognized disk label. Using `sfdisk --dump` also yield the error `does not contain a recognized partition table`. The disk image can be found here https://cloud.debian.org/images/cloud/bookworm/20230802-1460/debian-12-genericcloud-amd64-20230802-1460.qcow2

Comment: @CristianCapsuna I downloaded the image, bound it to my system via `sudo qemu-nbd --connect=/dev/nbd0 debian-12-genericcloud-amd64-20230802-1460.qcow2` and then ran `sfdisk --dump /dev/nbd0`. It works perfectly fine. It also works from within the virtual machine. What are you doing differently?

Comment: Thank you for getting back to me @Hermann. The VM wouldn't boot after I ran `virt-resize` on the image mentioned. Without booting into the VM I could not run the commands to change the partition table. Do you know of a way to change the partition table on the `.qcow2` image without booting into it via a VM? I was able to get around this by using `qemu-img` instead to resize the image and the boot into the machine and use the command you mentioned to change the partition table to use the unallocated space.

Comment: Yes, the `sudo qemu-nbd --connect=/dev/nbd0 debian-12-genericcloud-amd64-20230802-1460.qcow2` method works on the host machine without booting the VM.

Comment: Understood. I will give that a try and come back with feedback.

Comment: Hi Hermann. I finally had time to look at what you shared and I was able to do what you said. I can indeed read the GPT table after connecting the drive. I haven't tried changing it but I suspect that can be done from your initial answer. If you add this bit of details about the NBD connection to your answer I am happy to accept it. Thank you for your time and patience. I learned a lot :)